# Products from Stripe are not pushing to Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I'm trying to make netflix clone with this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHYVxg-lJX4&t=109s but products from Stripe are not pushing to Firestore

i went through this tutorial 1000 times and did everything exactly the same, but they just don't transfer, i tried to add it manually, but the app doesn't work

Comment: Hello, for the community to help you you need to give more details about the error(s) you are encountering. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I don't have any errors, it's just that when he adds a product to Stripe in the video, it is immediately displayed in the firestore, but I don't

Comment: You need to debug your code and share what is and where is the problem. I have strong doubts someone will follow the entire video tutorial, implement it in his own environment and try to reproduce your problem... This is why I've added the link on How do I ask a good question in my 1st comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the tutorial, have you installed the Stripe Firebase Extension?

https://extensions.dev/extensions/stripe/firestore-stripe-payments

If this has been installed:

1. Navigate to your Firebase console
2. Select Extensions
3. Select your Stripe Firebase Extension
4. View all logs

Most likely this is a Stripe key issue if the Ext is installed correctly.

If working correctly your products will appear in your Firebase collection as defined in your Stripe extensions configuration. Most likely the `products` collection in your Firestore database.

Comment: thanks, it turns out I had to click on the "enable events" button

Comment: Oh, on the Stripe console? Glad it's resolved!

Comment: nope, in firebase, it's new feature so it wasn't mensioned in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know exactly what is the issue, but common problems could include but not limited to:

1. wrong secret key (different account, live mode instead of test, etc.)
2. incorrect rules (you can recheck the rules on the [video](https://youtu.be/AHYVxg-lJX4?t=2149))

You need to check the video again for any small detail that you might have missed.